# How to find file mimetype from binaryfield

Tags: python, django, file

I have a file model with a binary field

```
class File(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    file = models.BinaryField()
    name = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
```

I created a view that renders the file by id

```
def media(request, file_id):
    file = get_object_or_404(File, id=file_id)
    content = file.file
    return FileResponse(content, as_attachment=False, filename=file.name)
```

This is the output I get

> %PDF-1.4 3 0 obj <>>><>>>] /Contents 4 0 R>> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x�3R��2�35W(�*T0P�R0T(�Y@���@QC= PA�J��� �1Tp�W� �+R@&�ҹ6f� endstream endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 5 0 obj <>/Group <> /Length 19219 >> stream x��}K�m�U����F�?��{9���������h�(�U��+�[�z;��A�����HI'4h#z��

When the file type is already known, I can manually set `content_type` to either `application/pdf`, `image/png`... But this is a `BinaryField` and I have no idea what the user uploaded. How can I get the correct mimetype regardless of the file type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`python-magic`** package [pypi]](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/) to *guess* the MIME-type. You install this (in your virtual environment) with:

```
pip3 install python-magic
```

Then you can guess the mimetype based on the bytestream

```
from io import BytesIO
from magic import from_buffer as mime_from_buffer

def media(request, file_id):
    file = get_object_or_404(File, id=file_id)
    content = file.file
    with BytesIO(content) as f:
        mimetype = mime_from_buffer(f.read(), mime=True)
    # …
    return FileResponse(content, as_attachment=False, filename=file.name)
```

But this is a *guess*, not all files have a header that makes it clear what sort of data they are carrying, so in the end the guess can be incorrect.

> I have a file model with a binary field

It is often *not* a good idea to store large binary streams in the database. A database is often not very good in storing huge amounts of (binary) data, and often the database will be slower in retrieving, storing, etc. files than the filesystem. That is why a [**`FileField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField) will store in the database the path where to retrieve the file, and store the file content itself on a filesystem, or a dedicated storage server.

Comment: I tried it but it gives me this error on `mimetype = mime_from_buffer(content)` : `argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type`

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi: yes there was a mistake, you need to wrap it in a memorybuffer.

Comment: Now I get this : `object of type '_io.BytesIO' has no len()`

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi: exactly what is the type of `content`? `print(type(content))`?

Comment: I fixed it. Had to be like this : `mimetype = mime_from_buffer(f.read(), mime=True)`. Thanks

Comment: Don't you need to use the `mimetype` variable afterwards?